# can same app run on different cpu type but same operating system?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture

I have an application that formerly was running on an itanium suse 11,
I'm wondering to now Can I freely choose suse 11 intel support on new intel cpu?
what I mean is that , is there any chance that application affect by changing cpu type but not the operating system it use?

Comment: You need to specify more information then that. What language are you using? What kind of features are you using? Are you expecting binary compatibility, or just the ability to compile on the different systems?

Comment: This is actually what I'm looking for. We bought an application from some software vendors, Originaly it was on Itanium cpus and now I'm looking to change the cpu type to match it with my own inventory. The application can be compiled again, But I'm supposing that OS abstract the instruction set to application. please guide me if I'm wrong

Comment: So, you don't know what features of the language you are using (since you didn't write it) and you are OK with recompilation, because you have access to the source. You still haven't answered what language you are using, but it might not be necessary to know to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiled binaries will *not* run on both x86 and arm. However, it is very possible to compile binaries for each platform from the same source code. How likely this is depends on too many factors to list here; you will have to try compiling it yourself. Depending on the language, cross architecture compilation will have varying difficulty. With Java or Python or something similar, the architecture is unlikely to cause problems as long as your are on the same OS.

[Link to a GGC-centric guide.](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/dynaweb_docs/0530/SGI_EndUser/books/ClrC_UG/sgi_html/ch14.html)

Comment: so let clarify the solution, You mean that even I have a same application on same OS but different cpu architecture, I need to recompile the code based on new architecture. is it right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. The architecture is, by definition, which machine code the CPU uses. When you compile and get a binary, you get machine code (unless you are "compiling" to bytecode, like java).